# Java socket does not receive data

Tags: java, sockets

I have to write server application that request questions from client and receives an answer. This is my client code:

```
clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
        System.err.println("Client started");
//get questions
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        Question q = (Question)in.readObject();
//send answer
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        out.print("a1");
        out.flush();
```

and server code:

```
//sending questions
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        List<Question> quest = Questions.getInstance().getQuestions();
        out.writeObject(quest.get(0));
        out.flush();
    //get answer
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        String temp = null;
        while ((temp = in.readLine()) == null) {}
        String answer = temp;
```

Questions successfully sent and later received by client, but server never get answer (infinite loop while reading temp variable). What is the problem?

Comment: Your calling `out.print("a1");` on the client, but reading a line on the server using `in.readLine()`.  Shouldn't you be writing out using `println()` on the client, else the server never gets to the end of the line?

Comment: Pretty sure this is the issue... Why not post this as an answer, so this gets out of the unanswered list...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your calling out.print("a1"); on the client, but reading a line on the server using in.readLine(). Shouldn't you be writing out using println() on the client, else the server never gets to the end of the line? –  CodeChimp Nov 21 at 21:07

Thanks for CodeChimp